# SQLite Database lock on large query of INSERTS OR REPLACE

Tags: android, sqlite

I hope some one can help me with this, I currently have an android application which has an SQLite database which can execute a txt with an SQLite query for amending the database, my issue is when I use a large number of INSERT OR REPLACE I get an error DATABASE LOCKED AT LINE xxx (ever time I execute the same query its always a different line) This error seems to start occurring around 1600 Lines or more. Query currently is constructed like this for each line

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "TABLE003" VALUES('000001','Group1',NULL,'20140519163202','20140519163202');
```

I currently have 2700 line which I wish to execute, If I break the query down in to about 500 lines each I don't have an issue, is this a known is on large query of INSERT OR REPLACE? and is there a work around (other than breaking the query down in to separate query of 500 lines each)?

Comment: There is a single lock around the entire statement. Might the problem be concurrent accesses from other threads?

Comment: can you split it into an update and an insert ?

Comment: can you give me an example? I don't really have much to do with SQL.